# Efficient way of getting average area in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

Is there a more efficient way in determining the averages of a certain area in a given numpy array?  For simplicity, lets say I have a 5x5 array:

```
values = np.array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
                   [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
                   [2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
                   [3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
                   [4, 5, 6, 7, 8]])
```

I would like to get the averages of each coordinate, with a specified area size, assuming the array wraps around.  Lets say the certain area is size `2`, thus anything around a certain point within distance 2 will be considered.  For example, to get the average of the area from coordinate (2,2), we need to consider

```
      2,
   2, 3, 4,
2, 3, 4, 5, 6
   4, 5, 6,
      6,
```

Thus, the average will be `4.`

For coordinate (4, 4) we need to consider:

```
      6,
   6, 7, 3,
6, 7, 8, 4, 5
   3, 4, 0,
      5,
```

Thus the average will be `4.92.`

Currently, I have the following code below.  But since I have a for loop I feel like it could be improved.  Is there a way to just use numpy built in functions?

Is there a way to use np.vectorize to gather the subarrays (area), place it all in an array, then use np.einsum or something.

```
def get_average(matrix, loc, dist):
    sum = 0
    num = 0
    size, size = matrix.shape
    for y in range(-dist, dist + 1):
        for x in range(-dist + abs(y), dist - abs(y) + 1):
            y_ = (y + loc.y) % size
            x_ = (x + loc.x) % size

            sum += matrix[y_, x_]
            num += 1

    return sum/num

class Coord():
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

values = np.array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
                     [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
                     [2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
                     [3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
                     [4, 5, 6, 7, 8]])

height, width = values.shape

averages = np.zeros((height, width), dtype=np.float16)

for r in range(height):
    for c in range(width):
        loc = Coord(c, r)
        averages[r][c] = get_average(values, loc, 2)

print(averages)
```

Output:

```
[[ 3.07617188  2.92382812  3.5390625   4.15234375  4.        ]
 [ 2.92382812  2.76953125  3.38476562  4.          3.84570312]
 [ 3.5390625   3.38476562  4.          4.6171875   4.4609375 ]
 [ 4.15234375  4.          4.6171875   5.23046875  5.078125  ]
 [ 4.          3.84570312  4.4609375   5.078125    4.921875  ]]
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution is less efficient (slower) than yours but is just an example using [`numpy.ma`](https://www.numpy.org/devdocs/reference/maskedarray.generic.html) module.

Required libraries:

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.ma as ma
```

Define methods to do the job:

```
# build the shape of the area as a rhomboid
def rhomboid2(dim):
    size = 2*dim + 1
    matrix = np.ones((size,size))
    for y in range(-dim, dim + 1):
      for x in range(-dim + abs(y), dim - abs(y) + 1):
        matrix[(y + dim) % size, (x + dim) % size] = 0
    return matrix

# build a mask using the area shaped
def mask(matrix_shape, rhom_dim):
  mask = np.zeros(matrix_shape)
  bound = 2*rhom_dim+1
  rhom = rhomboid2(rhom_dim)
  mask[0:bound, 0:bound] = rhom
  # roll to set the position of the rhomboid to 0,0
  mask = np.roll(mask,-rhom_dim, axis = 0)
  mask = np.roll(mask,-rhom_dim, axis = 1)
  return mask
```

Then, iterate to build the result:

```
mask_ = mask((5,5), 2) # call the mask sized as values array with a rhomboid area of size 2
averages = np.zeros_like(values, dtype=np.float16) # initialize the recipient
# iterate over the mask to calculate the average
for y in range(len(mask_)):
  for x in range(len(mask_)):
    masked = ma.array(values, mask = mask_)
    averages[y,x] = np.mean(masked)
    mask_ = np.roll(mask_, 1, axis = 1)
  mask_ = np.roll(mask_, 1, axis = 0)
```

Which returns

```
# [[3.076 2.924 3.54  4.152 4.   ]
#  [2.924 2.77  3.385 4.    3.846]
#  [3.54  3.385 4.    4.617 4.46 ]
#  [4.152 4.    4.617 5.23  5.08 ]
#  [4.    3.846 4.46  5.08  4.92 ]]
```

Comment: I see.  Thanks for showing me an alternative though.